# Clicking the "add" Button within the fullcalendar cell overrides the Event's click

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

The click of the ADD EVENT field, inside the fullcalendar cell, is superimposing the click of the event.

I have an ADD field inside the cells of the fullcalendar, which creates a quick link to insert an event.

The problem is when the same cell (day) has an event.

I miss the event click that serves to detail.

I need the two clicks to work.

My Codepen

https://codepen.io/lucasmormilho/pen/qBXvaPj

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2021-11-07',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    eventClick: function(){ 
    alert("Details Event");//click details event
  },
    dayCellDidMount: function (arg) {
                if (!arg.el.classList.contains("fc-day-sun") && !arg.el.classList.contains("fc-day-sat") && !arg.el.classList.contains("fc-day-past")) {
                    var theElement = arg.el.querySelectorAll(".fc-daygrid-day-frame > .fc-daygrid-day-events")[0]
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        theElement.innerHTML = theElement.innerHTML + '<div class="text-center"><span style="color:Gray" onclick="AddEvento()" >ADD</span></div>';
                    }, 10)
                }
            },
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2021-11-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2021-11-07',
        end: '2021-11-10'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2021-11-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2021-11-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2021-11-11',
        end: '2021-11-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2021-11-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2021-11-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2021-11-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2021-11-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2021-11-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2021-11-19'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});

function AddEvento() {
        alert("ADD EVENT"); //click ADD event
    };
```

Comment: You don't need a button in each cell. Fullcalendar exposes the [dateClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick) and (even better) [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callbacks. They let you handle the user clicking/selecting a specific date, or a specific cell (or cells). From either of those callbacks you could then proceed to add an event

Comment: Thanks my friend...dateClick an select really solves my problem...updated my codpen...

Comment: Ok. I would personally recommend `select` as the better option though, because then in the timeGrid views the user can select a time as well as a date.